# Docker network in MAC

Tags: docker

I have 2 docker containers in the same network.
I have created a network by :

```
docker network create my_network
```

I am running a Landoop container in this network using:

```
docker run --rm -it -p 2181:2181 -p 3030:3030 -p 8081:8081 -p 8082:8082 
 -p 9092:9092 --net=my_network --name localkafka landoop/fast-data-dev
```

And I am running one more container using :

```
docker run -it --rm --net=my_network --name containerB 
containerName.
```

When i login inside **`containerB`** and try to ping  **`localkafka`** 
using :

```
container ping -c 5 localkafka
```

It succeeds.
But when I do

```
ping -c 5 localkafka:8081
ping: unknown host
```

What am I missing here? Any help is appreciated.

PS: I am using a MAC and I have to use the ports exposed by 1 container in another container B .

Comment: Have you looked inside your `/etc/resolv.conf`? Also, try adding --dns=127.0.0.1
If I remember correctly, Docker uses different DNS (internal resolver) when custom network is configured.

Answer (score 2):

Your issue is that you're misusing ping.

Read this: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732509(v=ws.10).aspx

Short answer - ping works via ICMP echo requests. You cannot ping a port because ports are a concept in transport layer protocols like TCP. So, `localkafka:8080` is treated as a host with that name, not a host:port pair.

You can use nmap instead or look for a third party application that behaves like ping but over a transport layer protocol.

Comment: So if ping -c 5 localkafka is successful. It means the ports are also available ? Or is there a way i can validate the availaibility of ports 9092 and 8082?

Comment: `telnet localkafka:8081` - quick and dirty

Comment: @AkhilanandBenkalVenkanna well, you can install a telnet client or nmap. . . or just search online for any number of tools that can scan tcp ports.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a mac, you probably have netcat (`nc`) installed. Netcat can be used to test if a port is open or not:

```
nc -zw2 localkafka 8081 &>/dev/null && echo open || echo closed
```

The -z option makes netcat connect without transferring data. The -w option is tells netcat to timeout after 2 seconds if no connection can be established.

If netcat isn't available, `/dev/tcp` can be used directly to test if a port is open:

```
{ echo > /dev/tcp/localkafka/8081; } > /dev/null 2>&1 && echo open || echo closed
```

Comment: Well, this is inside a Docker container and it doesn't have netcat and hence it is failing. But thanks anyway. I need to figure out to way to verify this.

Comment: Might be worth adding netcat to your container for testing.

Comment: Yeah trying to do that.Thanks